Are Replicants ever standard police?
As far as we know, (I think) K is only sent to retire Replicants. He has no normal policing role.
I could see humans, deeply resentful of Replicants who, after all, set the world back many years with their EMP tactic, absolutely object to using such entities as standard law enforcement.
On the other hand, K does seem unconstrained when dealing with humans -- when he is crashed in the huge waste-processing area, he defends himself against humans and later threatens the Faginesque character who runs the business employing hundreds of orphans. (And Love clearly kills natural-born humans as well as other Replicants.
Anyway: Are Replicants ever used against human law breakers or do they stick to dealing solely with other? (At least officially...)

In the source novel there's an entire police station filled with unaware replicants.

@Valorum: That is true, but I am talking about whether being a cop who deals directly with human criminals is an OFFICIAL role of any Replicant. My guess is, if that ever was a possibility, the events of 2049 queered the deal for Replicants.

The Blade Runner RPG allows you to play badged police roles (inspector, etc) as an Nexus-9 replicant. If you're a legit replicant you can only be a rookie due to the year in which the game is set. Obviously illegitimate replicants can be found in all sorts of roles, some more senior than others.
